# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 keeps dropping wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, iwlwifi

My wifi Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 keeps dropping wificonnection drops and the network to which I was connected disappears from the list of available networks in network manager. The only way to fix it is to disable wifi and re-enable it  How can I fix this.  I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64bit.  It mostly drops connections on the 5ghz network.  My other devices don't drop connections over wifi.

see logs and versions

```
rt@simon:~$ uname -a
Linux simon 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
rt@simon:~$


rt@simon:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.370777] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.381089] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.414637] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    3.414695] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    3.414913] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    3.630208] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    9.304838] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[    9.305068] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[  605.483174] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[  605.483396] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S

rt@simon:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e iwl -e 80211 | tail -n25
Aug 14 08:13:02 simon kernel: [    3.452780] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:13:02 simon kernel: [    3.630208] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
Aug 14 08:13:06 simon NetworkManager[1125]: <info> rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Aug 14 08:13:06 simon NetworkManager[1125]: <info> (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Aug 14 08:13:06 simon NetworkManager[1125]: <info> (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'iwlwifi' ifindex: 3)
Aug 14 08:13:06 simon kernel: [    9.304838] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Aug 14 08:13:06 simon kernel: [    9.305068] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.230162] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232330] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232332] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232333] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232334] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232335] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232336] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:14:18 simon kernel: [   81.232337] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:23:02 simon kernel: [  605.483174] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Aug 14 08:23:02 simon kernel: [  605.483396] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.223905] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228945] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228950] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228954] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228956] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228959] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228961] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Aug 14 08:23:18 simon kernel: [  621.228963] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what support told me to do to fix it, it worked somewhat until a new kernel came out.  It looks like every time a new kernel is installed in linux the 5ghz band becomes unstable and gets dropped after a couple seconds or minutes

Support Case: My wifi on my laptop keeps dropping the 5ghz network.
Product Model: gazp9

When I see the World regulatory domain updated, I'm led to believe that you are lacking a recent firmware update that should help with some of the issues with the card. There are actually two parts to the update. One was a kernel, and the other was firmware in the OS and should be coming in with your regular updates.

if you're unsure about things, you can certainly open a terminal and perform the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When done, fully reboot your system.

I also had to change my World regulatory domain to the **US** see below:

```
rt@simon:/tmp$ iw reg get
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS


rt@simon:/tmp$ sudo iw reg set US
[sudo] password for rt: 
rt@simon:/tmp$ iw reg get
country US:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40)
rt@simon:/tmp$
```